# Java JPanel Paint Scaling

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, graphics2d

Following code work for visualizing a molecule on a JPanel except it does not rescale when I change the size of JPanel at runtime. The Chemistry Development Kit is used for generating rendered Image. A molecule is passed to MoleculeViewer for visualizing. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: It's very hard to say what's wrong without a decent familiarity with the library that you are using. Since the library is not part of core Java and only used by few who visit this site (if any), this is a very localized question and this may not be the best site for finding a solution. Have you tried asking on a site geared towards users of the Chemistry Development Kit?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, however note that if the API returns an `Image` or `BufferedImage`, it is possible to resize the image.  Of course, better results will be obtained by the API generating an image of the required size, but that is between you and the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Adding following resolved the not redrawing upon scaling problem 

renderer.paint(molecule_, new AWTDrawVisitor(g2), new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, w, h), false);
            g2.dispose();
            }
            else
```

Answer (score 2):

```
What am I doing wrong??
```

- why you needed to `setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));`
- put your `image = new BufferedImage(this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);` as [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), then you can remove anything about `paintComponent()`
- then you can return `JLabel` instead of [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html), but `JLabel` is translucent by default, or put `JLabel` to the `JPanel` by using proper [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) in this case [BorderLayout.CENTER](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- you have to check how way you added `MoleculeViewer`, what `LayoutManager` is there used???, because only usage of `LayoutManager` can this job correctly to resize (or not resize) Container's childs with [Top-Level Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html),
- `MoleculeViewer` must retuns `PreferredSize` for its parent

Comment: I tried JLabel also. Same results. I can clearly see ResizeListener correctly setup the dimensions for image. But the actual molecular structure stuck in the very first size.